# How do I get a particular Id data from local Storage for editing in form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am storing data from a form into local Storage, but when I try to call the data for editing, it only loads the data with the last Id, and not loading the data of the particular item.

Here is my code for the edit function
`//User input to edit form
      $('#edit_employee_form').on('click' , function(){

```
  var editEmployee = JSON.stringify({
      id: employees.length,
      employeeno: $('#employeeno').val(),
      employeename:$('#employeename').val(),
      stateoforigine:$('#stateoforigine').val(),
      employeephone: $('#employeephone').val(),
      dateofbirth:$('#dateofbirth').val(),
      });

//Alter the slected data
localStorage.setItem("employees", JSON.stringify(employees));     
          return true;
  })

for (var i in employees){
```

var empData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(employees[i]));
    }`

Here is my code for editing a data

```
//register Edit button 
$('.edit_button').live('click', function(e){
    //alert('I was Cliked!');
      e.stopPropagation();
    var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(7);

    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employees'));
    $.each(data, function(a, b){
        $('#employeeno').val(b.employeeno);
        $('#employeename').val(b.employeename);
        $("#stateoforigine").val(b.stateoforigine);
        $('#employeephone').val(b.employeephone);
        $('#dateofbirth').val(b.dateofbirth);
        $('#id').val(b.id);
        $("#id").attr("readonly","readonly");
        $('#employeeno').focus();

         $.mobile.changePage('#add_employee_page');
                return true;`
```

Here is my local storage

```
[{"id":1,"employeeno":"DEF/234/20014","employeename":"Bill Gates","stateoforigine":"Osun","employeephone":"080765432","dateofbirth":"12/11/1965"},{"id":2,"employeeno":"DEF/234/20014","employeename":"Bill Gates","stateoforigine":"Osun","employeephone":"080765432","dateofbirth":"12/11/1966"},{"id":3,"employeeno":"DEF/234/20014","employeename":"Bill Gates","stateoforigine":"Osun","employeephone":"080765432","dateofbirth":"12/11/1966"},{"id":4,"employeeno":"DAST/003/2003","employeename":"Gold Base","stateoforigine":"","employeephone":"","dateofbirth":"12/03/1986"},
```

The key of the of the local Storage is employees.

How do I call the id's dynamically? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are overwriting your control assignment three times, with the last entry winning out. What you need to do is specify which ID you should use to identify the appropriate employee and map its values to your form controls:

```
$.each(data, function(a, b){
  if(b.id === YOUR_ID){
    $('#employeeno').val(b.employeeno);
    ...
    return false; //Break out of the loop once you have the data you need
  }
```

Comment: Am I supposed to comment these lines out //var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(7); and //var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employees'));?                       I get this error in the console data undefined.